# Masked Text Box - Hide Mask

Tags: c#, wpf, wpftoolkit, mask, maskedtextbox

I'm using the WPF Extended Toolkit, and I want to know if it's possible to hide the mask, and then while the user is typing, the MaskedTextBox starts to mask the text.

The default settings is to show the mask as text. For example, mask is

```
 (99)999-9999
```

the default text will be:

```
 (__)___-____
```

I want blank text, like a javascript mask.

**Edit:**

I already tried changing ClipboardMaskFormat to "ExcludePromptAndLiterals" and "HidePromptOnLeave" to true, but doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I'd guess you can do this with a `Behavior<MaskedTextBox>`

something like:

```
public class MaskVisibilityBehavior : Behavior<MaskedTextBox> {
  private FrameworkElement _contentPresenter;

  protected override void OnAttached() {
    base.OnAttached();
    AssociatedObject.Loaded += (sender, args) => {
      _contentPresenter = AssociatedObject.Template.FindName("PART_ContentHost", AssociatedObject) as FrameworkElement;
      if (_contentPresenter == null)
        throw new InvalidCastException();
      AssociatedObject.TextChanged += OnTextChanged;
      AssociatedObject.GotFocus += OnGotFocus;
      AssociatedObject.LostFocus += OnLostFocus;
      UpdateMaskVisibility();
    };
  }

  protected override void OnDetaching() {
    AssociatedObject.TextChanged -= OnTextChanged;
    AssociatedObject.GotFocus -= OnGotFocus;
    AssociatedObject.LostFocus -= OnLostFocus;
    base.OnDetaching();
  }

  private void OnLostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs) {
    UpdateMaskVisibility();
  }

  private void OnGotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs) {
    UpdateMaskVisibility();
  }

  private void OnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs textChangedEventArgs) {
    UpdateMaskVisibility();
  }

  private void UpdateMaskVisibility() {
    _contentPresenter.Visibility = AssociatedObject.MaskedTextProvider.AssignedEditPositionCount > 0 ||
                                    AssociatedObject.IsFocused
                                      ? Visibility.Visible
                                      : Visibility.Hidden;
  }
}
```

and usage:

```
<xctk:MaskedTextBox Mask="(000) 000-0000"
                    ValueDataType="{x:Type s:String}">
  <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <local:MaskVisibilityBehavior />
  </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</xctk:MaskedTextBox>
```

Now the `MaskedTextBox` hint format will only be visible either when it has focus or it has any valid `Value` in it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I needed to delete all the "_" characters, so the client won't be confused at the time that he/she types into the maskedtextbox an IP. What I did was

```
<wpx:MaskedTextBox IncludePromptInValue="True" IncludeLiteralsInValue="False" Mask="000,000,000,000" PromptChar=" "/>
```

I set PromptChat as " " (a blank space) and worked perfectly.